# Getting output from a running process

Tags: process, docker, output

I have a process running on a Linux machine that I would like to access the output from. It's in it's own container that I'm using `docker exec` to `su` into. With `ps` I can see:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 18:45 ?        00:00:00 python ./manage.py runserver
```

I thought I could do this with

```
fg 1
```

but that did not work. How can I capture the output of this already running process?

Comment: NEVER run the django (or any other framework's) dev server as root!

Comment: Its output should be going to standard out.  You can see what this is attached to with `ls -l /prod/1/fd`, but it's entirely likely these will be bound to `/dev/null`, in which case the output is, put simply, gone.

Comment: You get the output in whatever terminal you started it in. Or did you close it? If yes, just kill the process and start it in a new terminal.

Comment: How in the world would `python` be PID 1 anyhow?

Comment: @ThiefMaster It's in it's own container that I'm using `docker exec` to `su` into.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Docker. This is an XY question. He actually wants to know how to access stdout of a docker container...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`docker logs <yourcontainer>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) on the host to read its stdout. Add `--follow` to keep the output going.

Answer (score 0):

You can only `fg` a job (or process) which you have run on the current terminal and either suspended (e. g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) and/or sent to run in the background (e. g. with `bg`).  Chances are exceedingly unlikely that PID 1 is *on* the current terminal; it is usually binding its standard input, output, and error streams to `/dev/null`.  You can check with:

```
$ sudo ls -l /proc/1/fd/{0,1,2}
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 28 15:13 /proc/1/fd/0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 28 15:13 /proc/1/fd/1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 28 15:13 /proc/1/fd/2 -> /dev/null
```

You can only check on the file descriptors for processes which you own, which is why `sudo` is needed here.  The roles of these descriptors are as follows for any process:

- `fd/0` - Standard input
- `fd/1` - Standard output
- `fd/2` - Standard error

Comment: Sadly I don't have `sudo`. I updated the question with some more detail.